# Simple way of scrolling over a certain rectangle with a JScrollPane and a JPanel (custom)

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have created a custom JPanel class called **ImagePanel**. I override the paintComponent method like this...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0,0, null);

}
```

The purpose of the custom panel is to simply draw an image.

In my JFrame, I create a ScollPane that is added to the JFrame. When I created the ScrollPane though, I pass in the instance of my imagePanel, like this...

```
ip = new ImagePanel();
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(ip);
this.add(jsp);
```

Now all I want as an easy to use way of using the scroll bars to scroll over my image.  Right now the image is very large and scrollbars do not appear. I use the policy to make them visible, but the handles to the scrollbars are not there.

Does anyone know an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [JPanel#setPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) that will force the `JScrollPane` to show the scroll bar if needed.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
   super.paintComponent(g);
   g.drawImage(image, 0,0, null);
   // set the size of the panel based on image size
   setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
}
```

---

**EDIT**

**Setting `setPreferredSize()` inside overridden `paintComponent()` is not a good way.**

**You can do it in a simpler way using `JLabel`** as suggested by `@mKorbel`. For more info have a look at the comments below.

```
BufferedImage image = ...
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)); // set the icon

JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(label);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: never to set setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight())); inside repeatly fired paintComponent, override getPreferredSize for JPanel, as aside to use JLabel.setIcon for simple job

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks but I want to know one thing. Why it's working without any issue? Can I reproduce the issue? Meanwhile I'll update my post. `JLabel` is a good option.

Comment: paint/paintComponent/paitChildren is invoked from all mouse, key events, and from notifiers implemented in API, in this case will be works untill there is one simple task, everything about layout, sizing is considered as difficult, hard job, simple sizing must be known before paintComponent is called

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks a lot. Sometime I think in the OP's direction to solve the OP issue only.

Comment: @mKorbel I always try to avoid these methods.